# Dynamically adding row to the table dropdown list returns empty

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a Purchase order view in my ASP.net MVC project.

Here there is a section to select the supplier, when the user selects it, the ajax call run and get the supplier details as well as the supplier registred Items.

So there is a button called Add Items to dynamically add rows to the table which shows a Dropdown to select items and Qty, Amount, and total amount.

For the dropdown I'm using select2 to user to select items by searching it.

The issue is currently even the dropdown option has values, in the combo box it won't show.

But when I remove this line

**initializeSelect2(selectElement);**

Then it shows the dropdown options.

But when it does, the ajax call that change function didn't get the selected item ID.

I want to know why this initializeSelect2 option is not working as it used to.

Please note that for this project I'm using sneat free template and there is a limitation for the select2 on the free version of the theme.

But I'm not sure that would be the problem because for other sections the dropdown works.

This is my Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Initialize Select2 on the "Supplier" dropdown
  $("#Supplier.form-select").select2({
    placeholder: "--Select Supplier--"
  });

  // Handle click event for adding a new row
  $("#testAdd").click(function () {
    addNewRow();
  });

  var supplierOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Suppliers));

  // Populating the "Supplier" dropdown with options
  var supplierDropdown = $("#Supplier");
  $.each(supplierOptions, function (index, option) {
    var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
    supplierDropdown.append(optionElement);
  });

  // Adding the "Create New Supplier" option to the supplier dropdown
  supplierDropdown.append($('<option>', {
    value: "new_supplier",
    text: "Create New Supplier"
  }));

  $(".form-select#Supplier").on("change", function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val(); // Get the selected value from the dropdown

    if (selectedValue === "new_supplier") {
      $("#newSupplierFields").show();
      setSupplierNameRequired(true); // Set the "Supplier Name" field as required
      // Reset the values in the input fields
      $("#SupplierName, #AddressLine01, #AddressLine02, #ContactNumber").val("").prop("readonly", false);
    } else {
      // Set the values in the input fields to read-only
      $("#SupplierName, #AddressLine01, #AddressLine02, #ContactNumber").prop("readonly", true);
      setSupplierNameRequired(false); // Remove required for the "Supplier Name" field

      $.ajax({
        url: rootDir + 'Ajax/AutocompleteSupplierFromName', // Replace with your actual AJAX URL
        type: "POST", // or "GET" depending on your requirements
        data: {
          SupplierID: selectedValue
        }, // Pass any data you need for the AJAX call
        dataType: "json", // The expected data type in the response
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.Success == true) {
            dropdownOptions = data.items;
            if (data.Supplier_Name != "") {
              $("#newSupplierFields").show();
              $("#SupplierName, #AddressLine01, #AddressLine02, #ContactNumber").prop("readonly", true);
              document.getElementById('Supplier_Name').value = data.supName;
              document.getElementById('AddressLine01').value = data.supAddress01;
              document.getElementById('AddressLine02').value = data.supAddress02;
              document.getElementById('ContactNumber').value = data.supContact;
              $(".SupplierIDClass").val(data.supID);

            }

          }
        },
        error: function (error) {
          // Handle any errors that occurred during the AJAX call
          console.log("Error:", error);
        }
      });
    }
  });

});

// Handle click event for the "Add" button
$("#add").click(function () {
  addNewRow();
});

 // Function to add a new row to the table
 function addNewRow() {
   var newRow = $(
     '<tr id="tablerow' +
     counter +
     '" class="poSet"> ' +
     "<td>" +
     '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
     counter +
     "</strong></label>" +
     "</td>" +
     '<td width="40%">' +
     '<select class="form-select ItemId" data-id=' +
     counter +
     ' name="Item_Id[' +
     counter +
     ']" id="ItemId[' +
     counter +
     ']" required="required"> <option></option> ' +
     "</select>" +
     "</td>" +
     '<td width="10%">' +
     '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
     counter +
     ']" value="1" id="Qty[' +
     counter +
     ']"  data-QtyId=' +
     counter +
     ' required="required" />' +
     "</td>" +
     '<td width="10%">' +
     '<input type="text" class="form-control MeasureBy" name="MeasureBy[' +
     counter +
     ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' +
     counter +
     ']" readonly />' +
     "</td>" +
     '<td width="20%">' +
     '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
     counter +
     ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' +
     counter +
     ']"  data-PriceId=' +
     counter +
     '  required="required" />' +
     "</td>" +
     '<td width="8%">' +
     '<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control lineDisc" name="Line_Discount[' +
     counter +
     ']" value="0.00" id="Line_Discount[' +
     counter +
     ']"  data-Line_DiscountId=' +
     counter +
     '  required="required" />' +
     "</td>" +
     '<td width="20%">' +
     '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
     counter +
     ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' +
     counter +
     ']"    required="required" />' +
     "</td>" +
     "<td>" +
     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
     counter +
     ');">x</button>' +
     "</td>" +
     "</tr>"
   );

   var selectElement = newRow.find(".ItemId"); // Find the <select> element in the new row

   selectElement.empty();
   $.each(dropdownOptions, function (index, option) {
     var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
     selectElement.append(optionElement);
   });

   newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

   // Initialize Select2 on the newly added dropdown

   initializeSelect2(selectElement);

   counter++;

   newRow.find(".Qty, .UnitPrice, .lineDisc").on("change", function () {
     updateLineTotal(newRow);

     updateSubtotal();

   });

   selectElement.on("change", function () {
     var selectedItemId = $(this).val();
     if (selectedItemId) {
       // Perform the AJAX call here
       $.ajax({
         url: rootDir + 'Ajax/GetItemPrice',
         type: "POST", // or "GET" depending on your requirements
         data: {
           itemId: selectedItemId
         },
         dataType: "json", // The expected data type in the response
         success: function (data) {
           newRow.find(".MeasureBy").val(data.Measure);
           newRow.find(".UnitPrice").val(data.UnitP);
           newRow.find(".LineDiscount").val(data.Discount);
           updateLineTotal(newRow);

           updateSubtotal();
         },
         error: function (error) {
           // Handle any errors that occurred during the AJAX call
           console.log("Error:", error);
         }
       });
     }
   });

   return newRow;
 }

 // Function to initialize Select2 on a dropdown
 function initializeSelect2(selectElement) {
   selectElement.select2({
     width: "100%",
     placeholder: "Select the Item",
   });

 }
```

Scripts I'm using

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

This is a sample view of the situation

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please click [edit] and make your post a [mcve] using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan hi, thanks for the advice, but how could I show minimal reproducible code while mentioning the issue, have to show the related complete code to understand developers. :| . Otherwise code will not be understand to others what I tried to do

Comment: Which means: Click [edit], then click the `[<>]` button, then paste RELEVANT HTML and script tags (changing your local jQuery for the one from the left menu), CDN frameworks (you have them, but add https: to the //) and RELEVANT CSS so we have a running version we can edit and check

Comment: code seems fine to me. From where you are getting `dropdownOptions` if the supplier is new?

Comment: @CodeThing It would be much easier if the code was runnable and for example showed console errors or such

Comment: I also suggest you look into template literals. This is easier to read without all the "+":  https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6gfv7edj/

Comment: Also you MUST have and empty value `<option value=""></option>` on the first option on a required select